# Change code based on Xcode build type

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I build my app as an Adhoc, I would like to set a specific var to `YES`.  Is it possible for my code to know what it is being built for, and change a part of the code if it is for debug or adhoc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Build Settings for a target you can set preprocessor symbols based on the build type you are doing, then in your code you can test for these using `#ifdef`/`#endif`, or to test for specific values you can use `#if`. Look up the preprocessor in the docs.

For example, this is commonly used to define the symbol `DEBUG` for debug builds and then conditionally include code:

```
 #ifdef DEBUG
     NSLog(@"The value of ix is %d", ix);
 #endif
```

Comment: Are you talking about Preprocessor Macros?  I am not seeing anything else.

Comment: Yes. Obj-C uses the same preprocessor as C(++). You can just define a symbol by writing its name, which you usually test for using `#ifdef`, or write `symbol=value` to assign a particular value, which you test for using `#if`.